# Scope of Javascript in Datapower (GatewayScript)

Tags: javascript, scope, ibm-datapower

I'm new to Datapower Gateway script (and Javascript) and following situation totally confuses me. Look:

```
var inputJson = "default";

//Reading json from input and covert it to string
session.input.readAsJSON( function ( error, json) {
    if ( error ) {
        session.reject( 'Input is not a valid JSON document' );
        return;
    }
    inputJson = JSON.stringify(json);
    console.debug("Inside: ", inputJson);
});

console.debug("Outside ", inputJson);
```

In Datapower console will be following:

"Inside: { long json string }"

"Outside: default"

It totally breaks my mind and distort my knowleges about variables scopes. Is it feature of javascript, datapower script implementation or what?

UPD. And another brain-cracked thing:

```
function getFile(options){
    var file="default";
    urlopen.open(options,function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.error("Unable to find file: "+JSON.stringify(error));
        }else{
            if(response.statusCode==200){
                response.readAsBuffer(function(error, responseData){
                    if(error){
                        console.error("Unable to open file: "+JSON.stringify(error));
                    }else{
                        console.error("Before: ", file);
                        file=responseData.toString('ascii');
                        console.error("After: ", file);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                console.error("Unable to open file: "+response.statusCode);
            }
        }
    });
    return file;
}
console.error("Func result: ", getFile(openSchemaOptions));
```

Console result:

1. "Func result: default" (sic!)
2. "Before: default"
3. "After: --json string--"

How it could be possible to  print function result before the function execution?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `session.input.readAsJson();` will take more time to execute. if we number the sequential execution of events in this peace of code:

```
// 1. functions and vars are moved automatically to the top by the js interpreter in your browser. So this is first
var inputJson = "default";

// 2. a function gets called passing another function as parameter => the callback function of readAsjson
session.input.readAsJSON(
    // 4. the callback function gets executed
    function ( error, json) {
        if ( error ) {
            session.reject( 'Input is not a valid JSON document' );
            return;
        }

        // 5. only executed if no error occured
        inputJson = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.debug("Inside: ", inputJson);
    }
);

// 3. the console output of inputJson, which was put on 'default'
console.debug("Outside ", inputJson);
```

This is featured by javaScript as there is only function scope. You can't expect the function parameter inside the `readAsJSON()` to execute prior to the console.debug of "outside".

Compare it with throwing 2 boomerangs but the first one takes more time to return.

Similar behavior can be rewritten:

```
function doMyJSON(json){
    // do stuff with json
    console.log(json);
}

function getMyJSON(error, json){
    if ( error ) { return; }
    doMyJSON(json);
}

session.input.readAsJSON(getMyJSON);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but how can I make sure via console that json-string have been placed in **inputJson** variable

Comment: By moving it inside the callback as you did. or if you really want to keep it separate, try finding info on "deferred" or "asynchronous" javaScript. At step 5 you can call your own function, passing json as parameter and you're of to a good start again.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful!